# Changing Text in div without toggling Div Visiblity

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my Div (Code Below) there is an onClick function that triggers the visibility of a second div, and there is also a content edible in the div as well.  When I click to change the text it also triggers the visibility of the second div.  How would I change the code so that I can click the text without changing the second div's visibility?

```
<div class="div1" id ="div1" onclick="onStepClicked()" style ="text-align:center"><p contenteditable="true" >Step 1</p></div>
```

Function:

```
function onStepClicked() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('div2');
        if (Visible === true) {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            Visible = false;
        }
        else {
            if (Visible === false) {
                elem.style.display = 'block';
                Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do u want to click, to change the visibility of second `div`? in first `div`, bu out of `p`?

Comment: Did that solve the problem? or the problem still exists?

Comment: How would you click on the DIV without clicking on the text? There's nothing else in the DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may trigger the click on the Parent `div` only and exclude the click on child in jQuery like this:

```
$("#div1").click(function(){
  $("#div2").css('visibility','hidden');
}).children().click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

If you are not OK with jQuery and are after a JavaScript - only solution, please leave a comment and let me know.

## UPDATE

If you are after a JavaScript solution, here U R:

**HTML**

```
<div id ="div1" onclick="onStepClicked()" >
    <p id="editable" contenteditable="true">Step 1</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function onStepClicked(){
    document.getElementById('div1').onclick = function(e) {
        if(e.target != document.getElementById('editable')) {
            document.getElementById('div2').style.visibility = 'hidden';          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am after a JavaScript only answer, but Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the element>element selector in your script. It will only affect the first child element and then stop from affecting sub-child elements.

Tutorial:
(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)